# Browse multiple file along with download and remove button for each using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create multiple files upload option.It comes with 2 options.

1) when user clicks on uploaded file name then file should be download.

2) Also just beside each file name delete option has to be there.

I can able to upload and delete files, but I don't have any idea to download uploaded files.

My requirement is when I clicks on File name,that should be go to backend people for download file.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Here is my code up to upload & delete file:

```
 <body>
   <input type='file' id='_file' multiple="multiple">
     <div id='files_list'><ul> </ul> </div>
 <script>
 $("#_file").change(function() {
 var ele = document.getElementById('_file');
 var result = ele.files;
 for(var x = 0;x< result.length;x++){
 var fle = result[x];
    $("#files_list ul").append("<li class='list_item'> <a href='#'>" + 
    fle.name + "</a>  <span class='remove'>X</span> </li>");        
 }
 $(document).on('click','.remove',function(){
    var span_id = $(this.parentNode).text();
    //$('.list_item'+span_id+'').remove();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: you won't upload any file with using code

Comment: Hi diavolic, Then please tell me how to upload and download file.

Comment: start from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php, see examples on the page